# Highcharts Data (using PHP JSON MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

When I used "data.php" data from the file itself doesn't read. But when I use "data.json" data from that file are showed in highcharts

```
 $(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("***data.php***", function(json) {

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Revenue vs. Overhead',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'No. of Events'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },

                 plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
                series: json
            });
        });

    });
```

**data.json**.....................................

```
    [{
    "name": "Revenue",
    "data": [23987, 24784, 25899, 25569, 25897, 25668, 24114, 23899, 24987, 25111, 25899, 23221]
}, {
    "name": "Overhead",
    "data": [21990, 22365, 21987, 22369, 22558, 22987, 23521, 23003, 22756, 23112, 22987, 22897]
}];
```

**data.php**......................

```
    <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("highcharts", $con);

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT revenue FROM projections_sample");
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'Revenue';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
    $rows['data'][] = $r['revenue'];
}

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT overhead FROM projections_sample");
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'Overhead';
while($rr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows1['data'][] = $rr['overhead'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows1);


print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Did you check if `$result` has a value?

Comment: You could try using `$.post('data.php',function(data){ data = jQuery.parse(data);` to call the data.php file and store the data in JSON style, and use then in your HighCharts.

Comment: @rmondesilva how will i check if there's a value? hehe

Comment: Add `print_r($result)` below your `print json_encode` then go directly to data.php by entering it in url bar in your browser. Make sure it prints value;

Comment: You can also check what is returned in JavaScript, maybe format is wrong: `console.log(json)`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value from PHP first by using AJAX. Like this below:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
          dataType: 'json',
          url: 'data.php',
          success: function(jsondata){

            $.getJSON("***jsondata***", function(json){
               // Your highchart codes here...
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: confusing. what will i put in ***jsondata****?